# How to UnitTest Retry feature of MassTransit

Tags: unit-testing, masstransit

I config my application like this:

[image]

It worked well, I want to add unit test for my consumer. So, I wonder, is there any way to set up the consumer to ReTry to an expect time in unit test. Like that:

[image]

Unfortunately, the consumer is not triggered by UseMessageRetry in StartUp configuration when run by unit test.

Could you help me on this topic?. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to actually configure `UseMessageRetry` within the `OnConfigureInMemoryBus` block prior to configuring the receive endpoint.

The first image, with the RabbitMQ configuration, isn't relevant in the second image with the test harness.